Conditional formatting on Piviot table that stays
Does anyone know how to have conditional formatting stick to a piviot table that will change in size based on the data that is fed to it?
for some reason anytime i update my raw data, my conditional formatting changes and no longer includes the area my piviot table is in and i have to fix the rule again.

What research have you done regarding this and what have you tried so far?

Based on your needs, setting number formatting in pivot table is the simplest Design the layout and format of a PivotTable - Microsoft Support

A bit of web searching gives me this:

Pivot tables have their own formatting which, by default, will overwrite other formats applied to them when they refresh.

The solution appears to be to make sure you're applying the Conditional Formatting the right way.
Solution:
In the Apply rule to section at the top of the Conditional Formatting window, make sure you select one of the "All cells showing..." options.
Solutions found here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/refreshing-data-in-pivot-table-removes-color-rules/380a52de-c960-46db-8bc8-a137d52eb144
https://exceljet.net/pivot-tables/pivot-table-conditional-formatting

Note that even set this way, Conditional Formatting will be lost if you remove the Target field from the Pivot Table.

thanks i found the link https://exceljet.net/pivot-tables/pivot-table-conditional-formatting helpful.
Seems like the key part to this is that the formatting will only work on any type of numeric areas where the values are being considered.  otherwise the option doesn't appear.
